# Dropdown list selecting a filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js

I'm trying to get every properties of a json object in order to create a dropdown list.

I'm going to explain myself, for example :

I've got 2 json objects :

```
{"name":"Paul","age":"18","sport":"Basket","color":"Green"}
{"name":"Jhon","age":"20","sport":"Basket","fruit":"banana", "number":"5"}
```

I've got a dropdown list within `{name,age,sport,color,fruit,number}`.
If I select name, I've got a second dropdown list within `{Paul,Jhon}`.

I'm using AngularJS, Node.js

I know that after getting every properties I have to apply unicity filter, to only have the differents properties but not the occurence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming ES6 is good and we can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to return unique values (if no - you can use [some other techniques to get an array with unique elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)) you can use [`ngChange` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) to detect changes of the first select and populated options for the second select. So the controller and markup will look like:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($scope) {
  var ctrl = this;

  var data = [
    {"name":"Paul","age":"18","sport":"Basket","color":"Green"}, 
    {"name":"Jhon","age":"20","sport":"Basket","fruit":"banana", "number":"5"},
    {"name":"Mark","age":"22","sport":"Football","color":"Red", "number":"5"} 
  ];

  ctrl.objKeys = getUniqueKeys(data);
  ctrl.objVals = [];
  ctrl.keyChanged = keyChanged;

  function keyChanged(key) {
    ctrl.objVals = getUnique(data.map(function(obj) { return obj[key] }).filter(function(obj) { return !!obj; })); //get the values and filter only the ones are defined
  }

  function getUnique(arr) {
    return [...new Set(arr)]; //get array with unique values
  }

  function getUniqueKeys(arr) {
    return getUnique([].concat.apply([], arr.map(function(obj) { return Object.keys(obj); }))); //get the property names
  }

  return ctrl;
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as $ctrl">

  <select ng-model="objKey" ng-change="$ctrl.keyChanged(objKey)"
    ng-options="k for k in $ctrl.objKeys track by k"></select>

  <select ng-if="$ctrl.objVals.length" ng-model="objVal" 
    ng-options="k for k in $ctrl.objVals track by k"></select>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May not be perfect but it is working

HTML:

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="itemChanged()" ng-options="item for item in list1">
      </select>
      <select ng-model="second" ng-options="lst for lst in list2 "></select>

 </div>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.list1 = ["name","age","sport","color","fruit","number"];
$scope.data = [{"name":"Paul","age":"18","sport":"Basket","color":"Green"},{"name":"Jhon","age":"20","sport":"Basket","fruit":"banana", "number":"5"}];
  $scope.itemChanged = function() {
   var prop = $scope.selectedItem;     
   $scope.list2 = [];
   $scope.data.forEach(x => {
     if(x[prop] && $scope.list2.indexOf(x[prop])) {
       $scope.list2.push(x[prop]);
     }      
   });
  };
});
```

Jsfiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sathvike/vzzmrnvL/